# Whitening floor grout (1-inch tiles)

Tags: tile, grout

A bathroom floor's grout is to be whitened.  A Google search listed [all sort of remedies](http://www.wikihow.com/Whiten-Grout) including bleach, vinegar, peroxide, [commercial solutions](http://www.homedepot.com/p/ZEP-32-fl-oz-Grout-Cleaner-and-Whitener-ZU104632/100619266).

I would like to avoid having to use a brush and apply a solution with a mop or similar.  If you have experience excellent success with a particular solution, I'd appreciate hearing from you and any lessons-learned.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a good bleach soak first. I have mosaic tile countertops with white grout, and a good bleach soak removes any of the evils my wife can dole out...

Comment: We have 6" white tiles and white grout on the floor of a bathroom. The grout has gotten soiled. I wasn't going to use bleach because I thought the darkening was mineral soil which doesn't bleach, but I might try it on a small area.